# Script to rename assets folder (in script to unzip zip file to html)

Tags: zsh, rename, assets

Trying to import html from Nimbus notes into Obsidian. A bit of a mess. Nimbus exports everything into zip files, and when you open the zip files it unzips to a folder named after the note, and that folder contains the html file, named note.html, and an assets folder.

I want to rename all html files and assets folders.

I want to rename all note.html files in all folders.  I created a script that opens the zips into their own html files with recursive folders and renames the note.html file that was created by replacing “note” with the containing folder name. So each unzipped folder now contains a html file with its associated assets folder and/or another folder containing it’s own html file with its associated assets folder and/or another folder containing it’s own html file with its associated assets folder and/or another folder and so on, up to 7 levels deep.

Here is that script:

```
#!/bin/zsh

for zipfile in **/*.zip; do
    echo "Processing ZIP file: $zipfile"

    # Unzip recursively, preserving directory structure
    unzip -q -o "$zipfile" -d "${zipfile:r}"

    # Recursively find and rename note.html files
    for dir in "${zipfile:r}"/**/; do
        if [[ -f "$dir/note.html" ]]; then
            folder_name="${dir:t}"  # Extract folder name from path
            mv "$dir/note.html" "$dir/$folder_name.html"
            echo "Renamed note.html to $folder_name.html in $dir"
        fi
    done
done
```

After running the script, the basename of the html file is the same as the folder containing that file, and the assets directory is named assets. Perfect so far!

Now I want to further append that script to also rename all asset directories so that the name starts with the name of the folder in which it resides and is appendaged with "_assets".

As an example, if the folder named "foldername" initially contains a file named "note.html" and a folder named "assets", after running the final script it would contain a file named "foldername.html" and a folder (with the assets) named "foldername_assets"

This would happen recursively for all folders.

Important: the new html files still need to recognize that its assets are in the newly named assets folder.

Comment: Please create a smallest reproducible example to demonstrate the problem From my posting, I don't understand in point your program produces a different outcome than you expected. BTW, why don't you loop directly over the note.html files, i.e. `for note in "${zipfile:r}"/**/note.html(N)`.

Comment: My script renamed the note.html file. Now I want to rename its assets folder to match it.